# Intermittent Bootstrap layout issue MVC

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on a website for our family business and we have a product page which outlines our four key products. It's a bootstrap template that we purchased from wrapboostrap.com (I'm no graphic designer!) and all has been going well. This page however (http://ashfieldclutch.azurewebsites.net/Products) has been giving me a headache.

Occasionally on either mobile or desktop devices the layout plays up (see attached images).

[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

If you reload the page on either platform, it loads perfectly afterwards. I seem to be able to stop this behavior by removing this div:

```
<div class="row portfolio-wrapper">
```

However, on mobile devices, this removes the spacing I require between the product types so ideally it needs to stay.

Can anyone see what may be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simulate it on my side and found the fix. It happens in Chrome and Firefox, so I don't think it's a browser-specific issue.

There is inline style being added to that `<div>` that seems to be calculating the height incorrectly. I changed the height from `1402.234375px` to `1602.234375px` and that seems to resolve it.

See before and after screenshots below.

I think there might be some Javascript code that might be calculating the heights and adding them to the `<div>` on the fly.

**For the permanent fix**, you will have to fix the code that is generating these heights. I will continue to look on my side also for that code.

#### Before Fix:

[image: before fix]

#### After Fix.

[image: after fix]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I will contact the designer on wrapbootstrap.com I think as I can't find the solution in the js myself. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. There is a `main.js` file in the theme that has a bunch of Javascript functions, but since the code is minified (i.e. functions, variables are all 1 character), it's very hard to tell which function might be doing the calcs.

Comment: There is no main.js but there is a respond.js which is quite a file (340 lines). I'm guessing this could be it but it's way out of my depth. I contacted the theme creator today but no response as of yet.

Comment: Ok. Is the `respond.js` file online on your hosted site? If yes, and if you can link to it here, I can take a look...

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking back. Sure, it's up there at http://ashfieldclutch.azurewebsites.net/scripts/respond.js. Thank you.

Comment: That may not be it. `respond.js` is an open source polyfill library for older browsers. https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/src/respond.js

Comment: Hmm, I can see that paying more attention to it, sorry. There is http://ashfieldclutch.azurewebsites.net/scripts/custom.js and it appears to use http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ which on their example on that page does adjust the div height when you filter the symbols. This page I have originally had a filter but only having 4 product types, I decided not to use it. That isotape is minified on my site. I would bet that that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63207/discussion-between-paulpitchford-and-shiva).

Comment: It's not really a fix but commenting out the js in custom.js for the portfolio-wrapper stopped this happening. I'm not bothered about the animation anyway so it'll do for now. I'd still like to try and fix it though just for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

I've refreshed more than 20 times, but I've seen it.

It's not about the classes in `<div class="row portfolio-wrapper">`, but about the inline styling that's added to this div by your templates Javascript. It happens to miscalculate the height of the div container class `.portfolio-wrapper` once in a while, which causes the lower content to move up. Since I can't inspect the Javascript, I can't help you much further.

I think you're best of by contacting the template author, he can and will probably find you the cause.